# DDR4 memory modules with XMP and Intel Xeon E-2246G - possible?

Tags: memory, cpu, overclocking, xeon

is latest Intel XEON generation (E-2246G) able to operate with DDR4 set via XMP profile on higher frequency? (XEONs are not "unlocked" if I'm right (?))

Why do I ask? Well, if I put DDR4 modules certified to up to 2666 MHz into a MB supporting XMP RAM modules up to 2666 MHz, could they run on this frequency with this XEON? They certainly could with some Core i5 9xxx, but on XEON?

Any experience? Thank you...

PS: according to https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/191043/intel-xeon-e-2246g-processor-12m-cache-3-60-ghz.html this particular XEON should support 2666 MHz... but I would be calmer if anybody shared his/her experience with this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Confirmed on *E-2246G* + *WS C246 PRO* + *HyperX 32GB KIT 2666MHz DDR4* - in BIOS selected `X.M.P. Profile#1` and it's working properly (*[hwinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/)* reporting DDR4 clock around 1333).